# Offsetting currency fluctuations with investments abroad

Tags: mutual-funds, foreign-exchange, currency, usd-us-dollar, eur-euro

Say you you invest x euros at t0 in a mutual fund through a European exchange. After ten years, at t1, the investment doubles to 2x euros.

Would you end up with the same amount of euros at t1 if you converted x euros into dollars at t0, purchased shares in the same mutual fund through an American exchange at t0, sold them for dollars at t1, and then exchanged them to euros at t1?

These two sources claim that indeed you would end up with exactly the same amount of 2x euros either way, but I don't understand why that is:

- https://thunfinancial.com/home/american-expat-financial-advice-research-articles/managing-currency-risk-as-an-american-abroad-in-what-currency-should-i-save-and-invest/
- https://andrewhallam.com/2016/05/expatriate-investors-does-it-matter-which-currency-your-etf-is-listed-in/

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the ETFs as a currency of its own. So EUR>ETF then ETF>EUR is the same as EUR>USD>ETF, then ETF>USD>EUR.

In both cases, the money only spends the time between t0 and t1 while in this "ETF currency", and (almost) no time in EUR or USD.

This is of course a simplification and reality is a little more complicated, but the general idea holds.

Answer (score 2):

In both scenarios, the amount of the ETF that you hold at t0 is the same. Once you've bought the ETF, the currency that you bought it in isn't going to change its movement. So in both scenarios, you end up with the same value of ETF.

Comment: I could see that being true until before the last step in the process: exchanging USD for euros again. If the exchange rate is not favorable, it would discourage you from changing to euros. But I think both articles there would be no unfavorable exchange rate at the end due to some mechanism I don't yet understand.

Comment: @weltschmerz The value of the ETF is the same in both cases, so the amount of Euros that you get for selling it is the same. Can you be more clear as to what you're confused about?

Comment: For example, does this mean for a European mutual fund that when its value is determined at the end of the day, the same fund's value in USD traded at an American exchange is calculated by taking that value times that day's exchange rate?

Comment: At the end of *each* day, that is.

Comment: I'm basically trying to find variables that I could change that would break this :) Another is this: would it still work if you invested not in a European fund, but an Asian one, all else being equal?

Comment: @weltschmerz Suppose an ETF is trading at $100 in the US and €80 in Europe. The current exchange rate is 1 € = $1.12, so someone could buy a share of the ETF in Europe for €80, sell it for $100 in the US, then take that $100 and exchange it for €89.44. This would net them €9.44 of free money. This is known as "arbitrage". If this happened, it would rive up demand for the European ETF and drive up the supply of the US ETF, raising the price of the former and lowering the price of the latter until they are equal.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Does this work only for ETFs or for mutual funds as well? Or more broadly speaking, what asset classes does this not work for?

Comment: @weltschmerz Currencies are simply units for measuring value. If you measure something in feet, and measure it it in meters, and multiply the first number by the feet-to-meters conversion factor, you'll get the same number. The only way this wouldn't work is if there's some major friction, such as a country having restrictions on currency or security trading.